# Spring date datatype

Tags: java, spring

I have a `private  Date date;` attribute in my POJO class in spring.How can I configure it in .xml file using IOC.I know that there are some special beans needed for it, can anybody show me what are those beans inside spring 4 as  is removed from spring 4?

Comment: @Tichodroma, my bad , i just edited it.

Comment: @Tichodroma, this <ref local = "customDateEditor" />  does not work in spring 4 its been removed.

Comment: Then use `<ref bean="...">` instead of `local`.